# Adding objects to an array and then showing in a table

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js

I'm trying to learn Knockout.
In my little project, I want to type in a firstname, a surname, and add it to an array of 'people' objects - and then show the list in a table using a foreach.

https://jsfiddle.net/2pf07vdh/

I'm new to fiddler too, so don't think the knockout is loading (The little checkbox should hide and show stuff, but it's not), but with this, in my editor, I get an error:

```
knockout-3.4.1.js:72 Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "foreach: function (){return People }"(…)
```

That's when the screen loads.

And then when I try add an object to my array, I get this:

```
knockout-3.4.1.js:14 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined(…)
```

Can anyone see why I'm struggling so much? I think maybe I can't declare the 'Person' object like this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23085414/knockout-unable-to-process-binding-foreach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line:

```
self.People = ko.observableArray([Person]);
```

you're creating an observable array with a reference to a class/function in it. If you want to create an actual person, you'll have to use the `new` keyword. Note that `FirstName` will still be undefined.

```
self.People = ko.observableArray([]); // Opt 1. Initialize as empty list
self.People = ko.observableArray([new Person()]); // Opt 2. With empty person inside
```

`MySelected` has the same error.

You'll also have to fix some unclosed HTML tags. Additionally, I'd advice you to put your `Save` and `Delete` methods in `MyViewModel` rather than `window`.